# Where can I download a sample Django template?

Tags: python, django, templates

I just started working at a place as a front end developer where I need to build Django templates. I never worked with these before, does anyone know where I can download a sample template so I can look through the code structure?

I won't be doing any application development using the Django framework, only taking the variables the developer gives me and incorporating the in the html/css templates I build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of Open Source django apps that you could look at for inspiration. One example is [Zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia) which is a blogging application - there are dozens of templates in this project, see this [directory](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/tree/master/zinnia/templates). There are many other open source django projects on http://github.com and http://bitbucket.org

You should also take a look at the [official template documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), there are lots of snippets there that are very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice little tutorial.
http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/use_templates_in_django/

Also, Check out the Django Docs.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/